# Why are kotlin coroutines called asynchronous?

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, asynchronous

Jetbrains in every article about kotlin speaks about asynchronous programming. But I can't understand why are they called asynchronous?
As I understand kotlin coroutines - this is a state machine with pre-init thread pools. We have a worker thread pool and an io thread pool. For me this is just a multi threading programming. If we send a blocking code to the coroutine, a thread will be blocked. If we use async method(from default coroutines library) , it gives us an illusion asynchronous work, but this nothing but send 'job' to another thread.

Another question if we use async io with coroutines. But this is IO API async, not kotlin coroutines. Java has not good io async api in comparison with other languages (can be wrong). .NET as I know already rebuilt theirs async api (as IOCP) to use C# task and .NET has dedicated thread pool for waiting all io of apps, so one thread can handle many IO operations. But kotlin coroutines are not integrated to java nio and when we call nio from the coroutine (with or without Dispatcher.IO) we just ask a thread wait a data from nio. Java NIO has its own thread pool for epoll or iocp, so with kotlin coroutines we are creating overhead when asking Dispatcher.IO to give us a thread for waiting result from NIO, and after that NIO implementation creates own thread (pool) for waiting data from socket. Instead of one thread (pool) for waiting, we have two now.

So coroutines just allow us send job to another thread in an easy way. You can't do multiple things with one thread at the same time if your api doesn't implemented in async way with kotlin coroutines.

Comment: You really raised a lot of different matters here - it would be better to discuss this on Kotlin forums. Generally speaking, coroutines let you wait in the middle of execution without blocking any thread. Yes, if you perform blocking IO with coroutines then you need to block some IO thread. But if you suspend instead of blocking then no, you don't block any threads. Regarding the naming, I wouldn't call coroutines asynchronous. In fact, one of the main goals is to get the performance of asynchronous programming, but without asynchronous callbacks hell. Suspend functions are synchronous.

Comment: Because they’re async *to the calling code*. That a coroutine can block its  current thread doesn’t change that. You may be talking about semantics more than anything. The question around NIO is a completely different, but I’m not sure I see it as any different than a Java task/thread/whatever using NIO, which AFAIK isn’t uncommon at all.

Comment: Regarding NIO: never tried that, but it should be possible and pretty easy to wrap asynchronous channels with coroutines/suspend functions. This way we can e.g. perform 10 parallel IO ops, each of them will be traditional "blocking" (actually, suspending) `read()`/`write()` function and we will do this using only a single thread (or more, whatever we prefer). NIO will probably spawn some internal threads, but I guess it will use few of these, it won't create 10 threads. This way we have 2-4 threads to handle all 10 parallel connections. But once again - I didn't tried that myself.

Comment: @broot "wait in the middle of execution without blocking any thread" - I agree, but the same option gives us the thread. I mean, without async IO (network or disk reading) which is implemented with kotlin coroutines, we can't do async work, we just dispatch job to an another thread. For me async is when we give some io job to coroutine and coroutine thread will do smth else while waiting response. But kotlin coroutine thread will wait and do nothing, will not return to thread pool until IO job is finished. If we perform 10 IO jobs, 10 threads will be blocked (even if we call nio)

Comment: The simple answer to your question is that they aren't using as narrow a definition of the word asynchronous as you are expecting.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Yes, if your code does mostly blocking IO then running it inside coroutines won't give you any (?) performance benefits. It won't magically make blocking IO non-blocking - it will just spawn threads. But if you wrap async IO with coroutines, if you you use library that does this for you or you wait on something else than IO, e.g. another task, some delay, etc. then you can do this without wasting threads and still keep a synchronous nature of your code. And I think this is what coroutines are mostly about.

Comment: @broot thank you very much for your time and answers. You know, maybe it because my inner self perceives the world differently after .NET. When Microsoft presented async/await we also got async IO implementation out of the box. So I expected smth similar here too, but now I understand little bit more. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I think a decent suspending IO library is what we miss here. It probably won't be a part of standard library, because Kotlin's stdlib has to be included in the application as a library and therefore it should be kept slim. It seems JetBrains work on something like this (https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-io), but it is far from being ready. Right now we have other good solutions like `Ktor` web framework which does what I described, but for web applications. We also have some 3rd party libs with suspending APIs, but suspend API itself does not guarantee optimal use of threads/resources.

Comment: Well, the last commit is from a year ago, so it seems they don't really push this project.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to look at the problem from a different angle.
Coroutines are based on suspending functions. Suspending functions are asynchronous.

The fact that a coroutine is a state machine is irrelevant there. A state machine could be translated to a chain of asynchronous functions and vice versa.

Instead of looking at Dispatchers as "thread pools", you should look at them as a Reactor pattern or an Event Loop. Yes, you can block an event loop. However, it doesn't mean that the event loop isn't asynchronous or that you should do it.

What you call "an illusion of asynchronous job" is "an illusion" only if you don't use suspending functions inside it. Since a significant part of Kotlin code is suspending (flow, Ktor, etc.), in reality, most of your code will be effectively asynchronous.

Java's NIO has different abstractions from Kotlin: callbacks. Those can be translated to a coroutine using `suspendCancellableCoroutine`

The last part is mostly wrong:

> coroutines just allow us send job to another thread in an easy way. You can't do multiple things with one thread at the same time if your api doesn't implemented in async way with kotlin coroutines.

A single Dispatcher thread will context switch between multiple coroutines, unless one of the coroutines is blocking: doesn't use any suspend functions and performs IO or an CPU intensive task.

Answer (score 1):

They talk about async programming because coroutines primarily ([but not limited to](https://elizarov.medium.com/deep-recursion-with-coroutines-7c53e15993e3)) are sold as a library to make asynchronous programming easier(subjective). but as you rightly point out there is nothing async about coroutines themselves. if you executed blocking code in a coroutine it will block the underlying thread.

but the point to understand is that coroutines are only really advantageous when coupled with suspending functions, where a thread does nothing but wait for the result(callback). so instead of waiting you can use the same thread to do ten more such calls.
another major advantage is that async code written using coroutines is much easier to write and maintain. for example, following is async calling using callbacks

```
fun callAPI(){
    getToken{ token ->
        auth(token){ authResult ->
            doSomething(authResult){ finalResult ->
               // use final result
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this can be reduced to following using coroutines and suspending functions

```
fun callAPI() = scope.launch(){
    val token = getToken()
    val authResult = auth(token)
    val finalResult = doSomething(authResult)
}
```

Now its possible for you to use coroutines for launching multiple long running blocking tasks but you wouldn't see any advantage. because in that case coroutines are nothing but a useless abstraction above threads.